# Split Ionic Page into 2 vertical sections, make the second section scrollable and limit height

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to divide an IONIC page into 2 vertical sections. The first section holds an responsive YouTube iframe and the second section holds a list of items. The sum of the height of these 2 divs should be the total height of the page.

I have been able to make the YouTube video iframe responsive. Now I need to adjust the height of the items DIV so it takes up the rest of the height of the ion-content (the view page). I have tried various solutions with no success! Is there any way that we can adjust the height of the items DIV and make it scrollable? It scrolls fine when I define the height but not if the height is not defined. Can the height be calculated dynamically?  I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

HTML

```
<ion-content scroll="false">
  <!--  video wrapper -->
  <div class="videoDiv">
      <div class="videoWrapper">
        <div class="videoWrapperIframe">
          <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-v2ZDYMu1Rc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!--  item wrapper -->
  <div class="itamWrapper">
    <div class="itamWrapperItem">
      <ion-scroll delegate-handle="item" direction="y">
          <ol class="list">
          <li class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
          {{item.id}}
          </li>
         </ol>
      </ion-scroll>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

CSS

```
.videoDiv {
  display:block; 
  max-width: 400px; 
  margin-right: auto; 
  margin-left:auto;
}
.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
  background-color:#ededed;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.itamWrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display:block; 
  max-width: 600px; 
  margin-right: auto; 
  margin-left:auto; 
   background-color:red;
}
.itamWrapperItem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

You can check out the code on Code Pen https://codepen.io/codingSober/pen/PjWxJy 
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna lie, your code is very messy and there are random html tags and css rules in there for no reason.

I cannot clean it all up but here's some updated html + css that may be what you are looking for:

```html
<ion-view view-title="Live Now" hide-back-button="false">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content scroll="false">
    <!--  video wrapper -->
    <div class="videoDiv">
        <div class="videoWrapper">
          <div class="videoWrapperIframe">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-v2ZDYMu1Rc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--  item wrapper -->
    <div class="itamWrapper">
        <ion-scroll delegate-handle="item" direction="y">
            <ol class="list">
            <li class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
            {{item.id}}
            </li>
           </ol>
        </ion-scroll>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

```css
.videoDiv {
  display:block; 
  max-width: 400px; 
  margin-right: auto; 
  margin-left:auto;
}
.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
  background-color:#ededed;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

ion-content {
  max-height: 100vw;
}

ion-scroll {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin-right: auto; 
  margin-left: auto; 
}

.itamWrapper {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't solve the issue! It acts as before and there's no scrolling in the items div!